# VB 2013 How to Convert Working Code to Dynamic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dynamic, visual-studio-2013

Hello I have a working code for a project i am making...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FolderDlg = FolderBrowserDialog1
    'Checks if there is a value to the Selected folder

    If FolderDlg.SelectedPath = "" Then


        'If no value asks to set one
        MsgBox("Please Set a Directory")

        FolderDlg.ShowDialog()
        If DialogResult.OK Then
            Button1.Text = Path.GetFileName(FolderDlg.SelectedPath)
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", FolderDlg.SelectedPath)

End Sub
```

I want to be able to have "AddNew"  Button that creates a a copy of this code. I know how to create dynamic buttons but they all call the same FolderBrowserDialog..

**EDIT** This is My Add New Button That Creates Buttons With Tags And Also Creates FolderBrowserDialogs with Tags.

```
   Private Sub AddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddNew.Click

    Dim count As Integer = FloLay.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList().Count
    Dim button As New Button()
    count = FloLay.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList().Count
    'button.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(150, 25 * count)
    'button.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
    button.Name = "button_" & (count + 1)
    button.Text = "Button_ " & (count + 1)
    button.Tag = "Button_" & (count + 1)
    AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Set_Dir


    Dim FolderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog

    count = FloLay.Controls.OfType(Of FolderBrowserDialog)().ToList().Count

    FolderDlg.Tag = "FolderDlg_" & (count + 1)

    FloLay.Controls.Add(button)


End Sub
```

**EDIT 3** This is My **NEW NEW** Event Handler

```
     Private Sub Set_Dir(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    If btn.Tag Is Nothing Then
        Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
            fbd.ShowDialog()
            btn.Tag = fbd.SelectedPath

        End Using

    End If

    Dim path = CStr(btn.Tag)
    '   MsgBox(path)

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", path)
End Sub
```

Now only to Add the Button.Name = GetFileNAme and persistance after app restart or reboot

***EDIT 4***

```
 Private Sub Set_Dir(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    If btn.Tag Is Nothing Then
        Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
            fbd.ShowDialog()
            btn.Tag = fbd.SelectedPath
            btn.Text = path.GetFileName(fbd.SelectedPath)
        End Using
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Folderpath = CStr(btn.Tag)
    ' MsgBox(Folderpath)
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", Folderpath)

End Sub
```

Now It Works like a Charm!

Comment: sounds like you need IF statements more so than dynamic controls

Comment: Do you have an Example i might follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a copy of the code.  What you need to do is have the code in the event handler determine what to do based on the `Button` that was clicked.  When you create a `Button`, you can store some data in its `Tag` property.  In the event handler, the `sender` parameter is a reference to the object that raised the event, i.e. the `Button` that was clicked.  You can then get that data back from its `Tag` property and use it.  You would use that data to configure the `FolderBrowserDialog` in whatever manner is appropriate for that `Button`.  E.g.

Creating the `Button`:

```
Dim btn As New Button

AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonClicked
Me.Controls.Add(btn)
```

Inside the event handler:

```
Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)

If btn.Tag Is Nothing Then
    Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
        fbd.ShowDialog()
        btn.Tag = fbd.SelectedPath
    End Using
End If

Dim path = CStr(btn.Tag)

'Use path here.
```

Note that the `Tag` property is type `Object` so it can be anything you want.  It can be as simple as an `Integer` or as complex as a `DataSet`.  You simply cast it as the appropriate type in the event handler and then access all the data as normal.

Comment: Is there anyway you can show me a example of what you are talking about? Or share a link to one?

Comment: You don't create a `FolderBrowserDialog` when you create the `Button`.  You create the `FolderBrowserDialog` in the event handler and you configure it with the data that you get from the `Button`'s `Tag`.  That's what I said in the first place.

Comment: Now it keeps Making New Folder browsers see my ***EDIT 2***

Comment: You're making this hard when it's so simple.  Create a `FolderBrowserDialog` when the user clicks a `Button`, use it and then discard it.  It's that simple.  See the updated code in the answer.  Alternateively, add one to your form in the designer and simply configure it each time a `Button` is clicked.  Just don't try to keep a collection of dialogues.

Comment: Nope... Still after  having selected Path if i click same button The ShowDialog event Happens Once More

Comment: `ShowDialog` is a method, not an event.  If you do as I have shown then one dialogue will be shown for each `Button` click.  If you're seeing more than one dialogue displayed when you click a `Button` then you're not doing what I have shown.

Comment: Exactly everytime i click the ***same*** button it shows the Dialog. i want it to ask once then if clicked again it simply opens the Path set before....and for an new button to have its own path...if you se my working code all the way to top that is what happens on a form with a single FolderBrowser dialog .. it check is path is selected if not dialog shows up.. upon clicking again no dialog and process starts selected path

Comment: OK, I think I may have misunderstood the original question then.  The advice I've provided so far is still valid but you'll need to adjust it slightly.  You'll need to store something in the `Tag` of the `Button` to indicate that a folder path has been selected.  That might be as simple as storing the path alone or as a property of some other object.  See my updated code.

Comment: Thank You Sir!!!! It Works...i see now my error was trying to keep calling the FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath. But Now Using Process.start(path) it Works! Thank you ....look at my new edit.